# How to remove Android Slider Bottom Effect?

Tags: android, slider

Currently, I am using ***smarteist/android-image-slider*** for my app project.
The problem I am facing is, that I want to remove the default gray shading effect and make it transparent.
I have added one sample image, I want my slider to be like with no bottom shading.
Means: with **no** bottom effect.

How do I do that?
Is there any other libraries that I can use to get a more exact look like the sample image slider?

```
<com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderLayout 
android:id="@+id/imageSlider" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="250dp" 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

Have a look at the slider here 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4San.png

Comment: show us what already have

Comment: Show some code, up to now what you did for this.

Comment: are you using elevation for this?

Comment: `<com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderLayout
                android:id="@+id/imageSlider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
`

Comment: I am not using any elevation